# How to use page-break and avoid white space to split my div over multiple pages when printed?

Tags: javascript, php, css, page-break

On my page I have some content loaded from my database. All this content is placed inside a DIV, nicely styled with images, font styles and background image. I want the visitor to be able to print this content without losing the styles.

I get everything to work nicely, except for the pagebreak. Somehow whatever I try, there's always a small space placed beneath every div that makes my DIV result in a position slicely lower that it's previous. In other words: the more page's the content needs, the more of the DIV is cut into half and shown on the next page. See below for an illustration of my problem.

**The CSS**

```
@media all {
.page-break { 
    display: none; 
}

.wrapper_programmaker:after {
  padding-top: 70.71%;
  display: block ;
  content: '';
}
}

@media print {
.page-break { 
    display:inline-block; page-break-after: always;
}

.wrapper_programmaker:after {
  padding-top: 70.71%;
  margin-bottom: -0.9%;
  display:block;
  content: '';
}
}

.main_programmaker {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #282828;
  font-family: 'Frutiger', sans-serif;
}
```

**The PHP**

```
<div id="printableArea">
  <? mysqli_fetch_array { ?>
    <div class="wrapper_programmaker">
      <div class="main_programmaker" style="background-image:url(../images/BG.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:contain;">

        //way more divs and content that are irrelevant for this question

      </div>
    </div>
  <? } ?>
<div classs="page-break"></div>
</div>
```

**And the JS**

```
function printDiv(printableArea) {
    var printContents = document.getElementById('printableArea').innerHTML;  
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;       
    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;      
    window.print();      
    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

**Image example of my problem:**
[image: My problem example]

Comment: One thing is that you have a typo in the div that sets your page-break class. You have classs="page-break" , it should be class="page-break"

Comment: thanks, but that's just here on SO, it's not in my original code.